# How to overcome "the field must contain an integer" when encoding a variable in conn.request()?

Tags: python, api, urllib

I need to compose a URL's part like `"/fixtures?season=2020&team=33"` however the team id should remain variable. I approached it like this:

`required_id=spreadsheet.find_parse()` - here, I fetch a team_id as int

`r1=conn.request("GET", "/fixtures?season=2020&team=" + urlencode({"":required_id}), headers=headers)` - here, I want to merge the hardcoded part of the URL with my `required_id` variable.

However, I get the following:
`{'get': 'fixtures', 'parameters': {'season': '2020', 'team': '=33'}, 'errors': {'team': 'The Team field must contain an integer.'}, 'results': 0, 'paging': {'current': 1, 'total': 1}, 'response': []}`  - attention to "The Team field must contain an integer."

If I then just hardcode the URL, everything works just fine. How do I encode my variable as an integer? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you encoding a dictionary then? Why not just `f"/fixtures?season=2020&team={required_id}"`.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel If  ```r1=conn.request("GET", urlencode(f"/fixtures?season=2020&team={required_id}"), headers=headers)``` , then ```TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object```

Comment: You're still using urlencode when you do not need to. That's my point!

Comment: You do not need to urlencode an integer!

Comment: Do not blindly use functions without knowing what they do!

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Thanks a lot, it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

provide the parameter in the request header as [request documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/)

```
param = {'season':2020, 'team':<required_id>}
r1 = conn.request("GET", "/fixtures",params=param, headers=headers)
```

if you are coing with the current approach, then use

```
r1=conn.request("GET", f"/fixtures?season=2020&team={required_id}", headers=headers)
```